# ОтклеИвшаяся или отклеЕвшаяся полоса?

Tags: орфография

Я написал так. Семь тараканов сидели в своем “жилище”, под отклеевшейся полосой обоев.
(А "Word" исправляет на "отклеившейся")

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Кле**и**ть*. Я клею, ты кле**и**шь, он кле**и**т... Второе спряжение. *Откле**и**вшаяся полоса*.

Comment: А  при чем тут спряжение? Речь идет о безударном глагольном суффиксе И перед суффиксом ВШ  в причастии. В этом случае надо привести схему образования причастия (от основы прошедшего времени глагола): клеить - клеил - клеивший. Кроме того, надо объяснить выбор безударного глагольного суффикса в самом инфинитиве "клеить". Пожалуйста, давайте полные ответы.

Comment: @Sibylla Дайте полный ответ - и сообщество скажет Вам спасибо!

Comment: @М_Г сообщество в моем лице говорит спасибо без дополнительных условий.

Answer (score 1):

Клеить - клеившийся - отклеившийся - отклеившаяся - под отклеившейся