# СамоклеЯщаяся или самоклеЮщаяся табличка?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: табличка, пленка - самоклеЯщаяся или самоклеЮщаяся?

Comment: См также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430707/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%8d%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be/430708#430708

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Безусловно, пленка или табличка *самокле**я**щаяся*. Клеить — глагол второго спряжения, а это значит, что в причастиях, образованных от него, в любом случае будет писаться суффикс -ящ-.

Comment: Не понимаю, тогда на каком основании подчеркивает Гугл?да и по запросу на "самоклеЮщиеся" таблички больше вариантов

Comment: @ДИАНА Гугл может «подчеркивать» что хочет, однако это не всегда помогает установить правильное написание. Количество найденных страниц — тоже. А вот словарь как раз то, по чему надо проверять орфографию: http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F&all=x.